# Is there a way to scrape older post on Tumblr with Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, tumblr

Is there a way to scrape older posts on Tumblr. Right now I'm only allowed to get the last 20 posts.

```
import pytumblr
import json
import pandas as pd

client = pytumblr.TumblrRestClient(
  'umxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxfieN',
  'zOxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx4Uy',
  'S8xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxeN',
  'RIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxgm'
)

date_since = "2017-01-01"

hashtag = client.tagged("queerbating")
hashtag_json = json.dumps(hashtag)
#hashtag_data = open("hashtag.json", "w")
#.write(hashtag_json)

for post in hashtag:
    print(post["blog_name"])

#df = pd.read_json(hashtag_json)
#print ("done")
#df.to_csv("hashtag.csv")
#print("done")
```

Comment: According to the docs https://pypi.org/project/PyTumblr/ you just shared your secrets with the world. Go to Tumblr and invalidate them if you don't want malicious people to do things on your behalf. A better alternative is to put those into a `.env` file and use https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ to read them into environment variables.

Comment: From observing the network traffic of some Tumblr blogs, I can see, that there is a `/page/N` AJAX call be made once I scroll to the bottom. Perhaps you can loop over those?